Cmd.exe exited with code '128' with bitbbucket repo
When our ADO pipeline runs, it falls over when it tries to pull the npm dependencies as the pipeline doesn’t have access to the private Bitbucket repo. We were considering adding a step in the pipeline that would rewrite the package.json file from:
git@bitbucket.org:<team name>/repo.git

to:
git+https://<username>:<app-password>@bitbucket.org/<teamname>/repo.git

We could then have the username and app password as pipeline variables. This should allow the private repo to be pulled down when npm runs.
Our concern was that Bitbucket doesn’t allow app passwords to be scoped to specific repos. We worried that we would generate a password with broad read access to hundreds of repositories. We felt if we went down this path there should be a Bitbucket user that has read-only access to this one repo and that account should be used in the pipeline. We cannot add such users to Bitbucket ourselves and weren’t sure if this was the solution we should be pursuing.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.
Need to pull private Bitbucket repo in ADO


Your title mentions cmd and exit code 128, but your text description never mentions it?

I am getting that error in while running the ADO pipeline at npm install task

Please add errors as text code blocks instead of only screenshots. That will make it more accessible, readable, discoverable.

The error says it tried to use an ssh:// remote, not git+https://  like you said you changed it to.
